# RXJava - hot observables - safe cpu resources

Tags: rx-java

Here's a simple observable example:

```
observable
            .filter(...)
            .buffer(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .doOnNext(/* this is executed all the time... */)
            .filter(data -> data.size() > 0)
            .doOnNext(/* this is not executed because of the filter above... */)
            .flatMap(data -> Observable.from(data).distinctUntilChanged())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe();
```

**Problem/Question**

The observable that I get from the `buffer(...)` function is emitting result after result, mostly empty ones.

Is filtering the correct way to handle this problem with observables like this? Will having a lot of such subscriptions at the same time cost performance? Or should this be handled differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, yes, filter out what you don't need downstream.

> Will having a lot of such subscriptions at the same time cost performance?

Technically: yes. More timers, more active sequences on the computation thread. However, the overhead of the sequence may be far less than the business logic you execute.

To save on some overhead, I'd use `flatMapIterable`:

```
observable
    .filter(...)
    .buffer(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .doOnNext(/* this is executed all the time... */)
    .filter(data -> data.size() > 0)
    .doOnNext(/* this is not executed because of the filter above... */)
    .flatMapIterable(data -> data)               // <-----------------------------
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe();
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know. I now have to check why this setup does not need the nested call of `distinctUntilChanged` anymore, it works the same way as my example...

Comment: Data is not an `Observable` there but a `List` which doesn't have `distinctUntilChanged` in Java.

Comment: I've already understood it, was thinking something wrong first... Thanks